# extjs store sometimes calling create instead of update

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

We have the following store in ExtJS 4.2:

```
Ext.define('Example.store.BasketDocuments', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Example.model.Document',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    sorters: [
    {
        property: 'doc_type',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }
    ],
    proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: baseUrl + 'document_basket',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'items'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'
    },
    actionMethods: {create: "POST", read: "GET", update: "PUT", destroy: "DELETE"}
    }
});
```

It is attached to a grid with drag and drop functionality.

When we drag around 10 files (for 9 it works) to the grid which would immediately update the store, we get a server error, because we do not implement the POST function for URLs like

```
/api/document_basket/1964?_dc=1459498608890&{}
```

This is only for one entry.

For the others it would be

```
/api/document_basket?_dc=1459498608941&{}
```

which works.

Dragging only that single entry works.

So ExtJS is sending a POST request with an ID in the URL, which should be a PUT instead? Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this in my project.

Reason was that I was adding items to the store in a loop - so after each add of - let's say 14 files - a sync was done.

I discovered that there were 105 requests, which is just 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14 so this caused a race condition.

Solution is to disable syncing before the loop:

```
onBeforeDropItem: function (node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropHandlers, eOpts) {
    dropHandlers.cancelDrop();

    var store = Ext.getStore('BasketDocuments');

    store.suspendAutoSync(); // new

    if (node.id != 'documenttreepanel-body') {
        Ext.Array.each(data.records, function (r, index) {
            r = r.copy();
            r.phantom = true;
            r.data.id = null;
            r.data.download_size = 1;
            r.data.download_type = 1;

            if (r.data.doc_type == 1) {
                if (r.data.count == 0) {
                    Ext.create('Ext.window.MessageBox').show({
                        title: Ext.ux.Translate.get('Info'),
                        msg: Ext.ux.Translate.get('Ordner') + '<b>' + r.data.name + '</b>' + Ext.ux.Translate.get(' Is empty and cannot be added ') + '.',
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                        modal: true
                    });
                } else {
                    store.add(r);
                }
            } else {
                store.add(r);
            }
        });
    }

    store.sync(); // new
    store.resumeAutoSync(); // new
```